# href="mailto:" not working in jQuery colapsible-set

Tags: jquery, css

Any idea why the mail link in the last colapslible does not work? It is displayed but the link has no function when clicked:

```
<div data-role="page" id="info"> 

<img src="images/bb.jpg" class="background"></img>

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Info</h1>

</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">

  <div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="colset">
         <h3>Text</h3>
         <p>text</p> 
         <p>more text</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="colset">
         <h3>Text 2</h3>
            <p>details 2</p> 
         </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="colset">
        <h3>About</h3>
        <p>text 3</p>
        <p>text 4</p>
        <a href="mailto:info@example.com">Mail me</a>
    </div>
  </div>     

  </div><!-- /content-->

</div><!-- /page info -->
```

the CSS looks as follows:

```
.colset {

    background: #ddf0f8

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're going to need to show the javascript you're using. You're probably returning false or preventing the default action of the link somewhere...

Comment: This doesn't matter really, but you are closing the `<img>` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

What web browser are you using? If you happen to be using Firefox, please take a look at [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/791166).

Also you might want to disable some add-ons in case these links are blocked for security reasons.

Alternatively, you might want to try this approach and see if it'd help.

> A possible solution might be to reset the mail client by going to
>   Control Panel --> Default Programs --> Set your program defaults,
>   clicking Windows Live Mail, or some other mail program, and confirm
>   that it is set as the default mail program. If Windows Live Mail
>   doesn't work, then it might be useful to check if others do, to find
>   out if it is Windows Live Mail that is causing the problem.